# most concise way to operate over two lists, returning list of lists in python

Tags: python, regex, list, iterator

I have a list of regular expressions and a list of target phrases.  I'm looking to match each  piece of regex against each phrase, returning a list of lists, with the rows being the terms and columns being the regex, and the data being either the match object or `None`, as concisely as possible.  My current approach does this matching, but unfortunately gives me a single long list, instead of the list of lists I described.

Here's what i have:

```
import re
regexLines=['[^/]*/b/[^/]*', 'a/[^/]*/[^/]*', '[^/]*/[^/]*/c', 'foo/bar/baz', 'w/x/[^/]*/[^/]*', '[^/]*/x/y/z']
targetLines=['/w/x/y/z/', 'a/b/c', 'foo/', 'foo/bar/', 'foo/bar/baz/']

###compiling the regex lines
matchLines=[re.compile(i) for i in regexLines]

matchMatrix=[i.match(j) for i in matchLines for j in targetLines]

matchMatrix
[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x04095368>, None, None, None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match     object at 0x0411A3D8>, None, None, None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0411A410>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0411A448>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I instead want something that looks like this, with each row representing the matches for a phrase:

```
[[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x04095368>, None, None, None, None], 
[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0411A3D8>, None, None, None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0411A410>], etc. etc.
```

I could write out a verbose loop that could do what I want, but my inkling is that there's a concise, Pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you want:

```
matchMatrix = [[i.match(j) for j in targetLines] for i in matchLines ]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint([[i.match(j) for j in targetLines] for i in matchLines ])
[[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9b5d058>, None, None, None],
 [None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9b5d100>, None, None, None],
 [None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9b5d138>, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9b5d170>],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None]]
```